# Reversing an entire paragraph of text instead of reversing each consecutive line

Tags: java

I was trying to read a text file using FileInputStream and wanted to display all of the words in reverse (so the last word will be the first word etc.) I was able to display all the letters in reverse using a string tokenizer, but not the words.. I've tried a few different methods now and just couldn't seem to do this

Using an ArrayList I could reverse the lines (print the last line first and the first line last).. but I couldn't find a way to reverse all the words

here is what is in my "test.txt" file:

> One characteristic of Java is portability, which means that computer programs written in the Java language must run similarly on
>   any 
>   hardware/operating-system platform. This is achieved by compiling the Java language code to an intermediate representation called Java 
>   bytecode, instead of directly to platform-specific machine code. Java bytecode instructions are analogous to machine code, but they are
>   intended to be interpreted 
>   by a virtual machine (VM) written specifically for the host hardware. End-users commonly use a Java Runtime Environment (JRE)
>   installed on their own machine for standalone Java applications, or in a Web browser for Java applets.

code:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RevWords6
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {   
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.txt"), "UTF-8"));                

        String lines = br.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();

        //while the data is not null
        while(lines != null)
        {   
            //String words[] = lines.split(" ");

            //track formatting
            if(lines != null)
            {   
                buffer.add("\n");
                buffer.add(lines);  //I wanted to put the words array in here instead of "lines" but didn't know how
            }

            lines=br.readLine();
        }

        //reads lines backwards from ArrayList buffer but wanted to read words from end-to-beginning
        for(int i = buffer.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(buffer.get(i));
        }

        br.close();
    }
}
```

output:

> installed on their own machine for standalone Java applications, or in
>   a Web browser for Java applets. by a virtual machine (VM) written
>   specifically for the host hardware. End-users commonly use a Java
>   Runtime Environment (JRE) bytecode, instead of directly to
>   platform-specific machine code. Java bytecode instructions are
>   analogous to machine code, but they are intended to be interpreted 
>   hardware/operating-system platform. This is achieved by compiling the
>   Java language code to an intermediate representation called Java  One
>   characteristic of Java is portability, which means that computer
>   programs written in the Java language must run similarly on any

As you can see it is printing the lines beginning from bottom to top, but I wanted the words beginning from bottom to top

and here I've tried to use a StringBuffer with a string array splitting the lines by one whitespace, but in this case I could only reverse each line and not reverse the entire paragraph

code:

```
import java.io.*;  


public class RevWords4
{   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Conor\\Documents\\test.txt"), "UTF-8"));               
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();   

        String line = br.readLine();
        String[] word = line.split(" ");

        while(line != null)
        {           
            if(line != null)
            {   
                word = line.split(" ");

                for(int i = word.length-1; i>=0; i--)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word[i] + " ");        
                    buffer.append(sb);          
                }

                buffer.append("\n");
            }

            line=br.readLine();
        }


        System.out.print(buffer);
        br.close();
    }
}
```

output:

> any on similarly run must language Java the in written programs
>   computer that means which portability, is Java of characteristic One 
>   Java called representation intermediate an to code language Java the
>   compiling by achieved is This platform. hardware/operating-system 
>   interpreted be to intended are they but code, machine to analogous are
>   instructions bytecode Java code. machine platform-specific to directly
>   of instead bytecode,  (JRE) Environment Runtime Java a use commonly
>   End-users hardware. host the for specifically written (VM) machine
>   virtual a by  applets. Java for browser Web a in or applications, Java
>   standalone for machine own their on installed

So I would happily accept any suggestions and tips on this, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the while loop a little bit did the trick for me:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String[] splitStr = lines.split(" ");
for (int i = splitStr.length; i > 0; i--) {
    str.append(splitStr[i - 1]).append(" ");
}

buffer.add(str.toString());  //I wanted to put the words array in here instead of "lines" but didn't know how
```

So, your complete code looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RevWords6
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {   
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.txt"), "UTF-8"));                

        String lines = br.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();

        //while the data is not null
        while(lines != null)
        {   
            //String words[] = lines.split(" ");

            //track formatting
            if(lines != null)
            {   
                buffer.add("\n");

                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String[] splitStr = lines.split(" ");
                for (int i = splitStr.length; i > 0; i--) {
                    str.append(splitStr[i - 1]).append(" ");
                }

                buffer.add(str.toString());  //I wanted to put the words array in here instead of "lines" but didn't know how
            }

            lines=br.readLine();
        }

        //reads lines backwards from ArrayList buffer but wanted to read words from end-to-beginning
        for(int i = buffer.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(buffer.get(i));
        }

        br.close();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
Having a custom reader that reads a line reversed might be a slightly better approach:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class ReversedLineBufferedReader extends BufferedReader {

    public ReversedLineBufferedReader(Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        String line = super.readLine();

        if (line == null) {
            return null;
        }

        StringBuilder reversedLine = new StringBuilder();
        if (line.length() > 0) {
            String[] splitString = line.split("\\b");
            for (int i = splitString.length; i > 0; i--) {
                reversedLine.append(splitString[i - 1]).append(" ");
            }
        }
        return reversedLine.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Split at word boundary would make it easier: String[] stringArray = s.split("\\b");